Source that boredom leads to sin
I remember learning that boredom leads to sin and that there’s a very explicit teaching that we learn this from. Anyone know the source?
*Im aware of Kiddushin 30b but that is specifically of idleness of Torah and evil inclination not affecting you if you learn but not explicit that in general if you’re bored it will lead to sin

Cf. Avos 2:2

Thanks, I know this might sound funny but that is only proof that if someone learns Torah and doesn’t do action then it leads to sin. Meaning that if Chas VeShalom someone doesn’t learn Torah to begin with, this wouldn’t apply - I am trying to prove to someone that currently doesn’t study Torah that boredom leads to sin and both this and the current answer aren’t clear enough proofs for this…any other suggestions are appreciated

It may actually be worse, as Pirkei Avos 3:4 https://www.sefaria.org/Pirkei_Avot.3.4?vhe=Torat_Emet_357&lang=bi

What is boredom in lashon chazal? If you mean idleness, that itself is a bit of a sin, isn't it?

Mishnah Ketubot 5:5:

שֶׁהַבַּטָּלָה מְבִיאָה לִידֵי זִמָּה
idleness leads to licentiousness


Thanks, it’s interesting that this is specifically in reference to a women. I understand that the general teaching could apply to men as well but I’m wondering if perhaps there is any other teaching that is stated in a more general case or is this the “main” source?

At the end of that mishna it also mentions שֶׁהַבַּטָּלָה מְבִיאָה לִידֵי שִׁעֲמוּם - (idleness leads to boredom) so the same root cause of idleness leads both to sin and to boredom. Not sure whether this also implies that boredom by definition leads to sin but I had a hunch that it might.

@EraserX While in Modern Hebrew שעמום means boredom, it doesn't necessarily have the same meaning in Mishnaic Hebrew. See e.g. Rashi there.

I definitely hear you re: Rashi's explanation of "שגעון".  However, if one now takes boredom out of the equation, does bitul itself inherently imply boredom and not mere idleness? and if not, then a statement of bitul => zima might not equate to boredom => zima

@ShtikaK'hodaah I really do think this is the source you are looking for. The context may be about women, but that's definitely not a limit on the principle.

@RabbiKaii thanks for the comment, I agree that the principle could be applied as I mentioned in my first comment but I still recall learning from a more explicit general teaching, although I very well could be wrong. I’d like to look into it a bit more before I accept. I’ve learned from this platform that the most voted or liked answer is not always correct (I’m not saying that’s the case here but I’d like to check is all). Thank you

@ShtikaK'hodaah indeed, and fair enough. I know that feeling

Pirkei Avos 3:4
רַבִּי חֲנִינָא בֶן חֲכִינַאי אוֹמֵר, הַנֵּעוֹר בַּלַּיְלָה וְהַמְהַלֵּךְ בַּדֶּרֶךְ יְחִידִי וְהַמְפַנֶּה לִבּוֹ לְבַטָּלָה, הֲרֵי זֶה מִתְחַיֵּב בְּנַפְשׁוֹ:
Rabbi Hananiah ben Hakinai said: one who stays awake at night or walks on the way alone and turns his heart to idle matters, behold, this man is mortally guilty.

Is this saying that idleness leads to sin, or that idleness is itself sinful?

@Alex well it means that idleness kills. Similarly, Rabbi Chanina ben Dosa in the episode of the snake says that the sin kills.

@Alex alternatively, killing oneself is a sin against oneself, as the Torah states - choose life.
